# PHP - problem with nested mysql_fetch_array() driving me crazy

Tags: php, mysql, nested, while-loop

The MySQL query:

```
SELECT title,alias,parent FROM '._prefix.'categories 
WHERE (language = \''._language.'\' || language = \'all\') 
&& status = \'published\'
ORDER BY rank ASC
```

The Result (from phpMyAdmin):

```
title    |  alias   |  parent
Home     | home     |    0
Todo     | todo     |    0
Multiuser| todo_mu  |    21
Modulsys | todo_mod |    21
```

The PHP:

```
while($c = mysql_fetch_array($category_result)) {
    if($c['parent'] == 0) {
        $output .= '<li><a href="'._rewrite_string.$c['alias'].'" title="'.$c['title'].'">'.$c['title'].'</a>';

        $output .= '<ul>';

        mysql_data_seek($category_result,0);

        while($d = mysql_fetch_array($category_result)) {

            $output .= '<li class="space_left"><a href="'._rewrite_string.$c['alias'].'/'.$d['alias'].'" title="'.$d['title'].'">'.$d['title'].'</a>';

            $output .= '</li>';

        }

        $output .= '</ul>';

        $output .= '</li>';
    }
}
```

This should generate a category list like that

cat 1

- subcat 1
- subcat 2

cat 2

cat 3

but it generates something like that

cat 1

- cat 1
- cat 2
- subcat 1
- subcat 2

using the mysql_fetch_array into another (nested) without using mysql_data_seek
causes an abort once the nested mysql_fetch_array was called. it only outputs cat1 and nothing more.

please provide me the solution, thank you

Comment: your problem isn't the nested fetch_array. Why do you rewind the data with  mysql_data_seek ?
what sort of query do you use to obtain your category_result?

Comment: This will be impossible to answer without the SQL result set.

Comment: Can you post what the SQL query is actually returning? I don't see any reason why you are nesting your fetch array at all. and the `mysql_data_seek` is not doing anything, from what I can tell.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think he is wanting to do the query again based on the current query result row. Not feeling up to writing out a speculative answer, so someone else is welcome to.

Comment: SQL details: http://img99.imageshack.us/img99/4776/unbenannt1ki.jpg

Comment: What does parent 21 mean? And it would really help your cause if you would include the details in the question, not link them from comments.

Comment: parent 21 means its a child of category with id 21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
while($c = mysql_fetch_array($category_result)) {
    $parent = $c['parent'];
    $next_row = $i + 1;

    $not_last_row = (mysql_data_seek($category_result, $next_row)); //Move ahead to get next parent or returns false if on last row...
    $next_parent = (!$not_last_row) ? $c['parent'] : FALSE;
    mysql_data_seek($category_result, $i); //Move back to current row

    $open_list = ($parent != $prev_parent);
    $close_list = (($parent > $next_parent) || !$not_last_row); //close list if next parent is smaller number or if this is last row.

    $output .= ($open_list) ? "<ul>" : "";

    $output .= '<li>'.$c['title'].'</li>';

    $output .= ($close_list) ? '</ul>' : "";

    $prev_parent = $parent; //Set this so that on next loop, we can see if they match
    $i++;
}
```

It's a bit rushed, but I think this is what you have in mind. Basically, if the previous parent does not match the current parent, open a list. If the current parent is greater than the next parent, close the list.

You will probably need to add something to account for it being the last iteration.

Comment: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64487341 bytes) ... looks like this is causing some memory overflow

Comment: That probably wouldn't be the case if you actually used a multi-dimensional array and then looped through that instead. How big is this list? Just the four?

Comment: yes only 4 at the moment... if i use your updated version i get an offset error with the mysql_data_seek ... but i think we are on the right way with that... but one bad point is that we do not have the "parent" alias for generating the url...

$c['alias'].'/'.$d['alias'] ... the c-alias

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the expected result. If you have the result set `a,b,c,d`, you are starting with `a` which is a parent category, so it rewinds to the start of the set, and iterates through `a,b,c,d` again as subcategories. Now you are at the end of the set so both loops will exit as there is no more data.

What you probably want to do is to read all the data into a PHP array first, then iterate over that and build some sort of a tree structure. You might also be able to build your tree structure directly in the mysql_fetch loop.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, there are also better ways to store your data. It's worth reading up on how to store trees and hierarchical data in SQL. Nested sets are probably what you want.

One other thing: don't use `mysql_fetch_array`, use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead. Otherwise you end up with numeric and associative keys and a row array which contains twice the amount of data it should.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the quick and dirty solution like this:

1. prepare 2 result sets with the same SQL query so that you'll get $category_result and $category_result2.
2. Then use $category_result for the outer loop and $category_result2 for the inner loop.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Think of what your code is doing:

1. fetches a row of data into `$c` and spits out the `cat1` header
2. Enters the inner loop and repeatedly fetches more data into `$d`, spitting out subcat1, subcat2, etc..
3. The loop reaches the end of the result set, and exits out into the parent `$c` loop
4. There's no more data to fetch, so the parent loop exits

Syntactically, if you were to strip away all the database operations, you're essentially doing this:

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {   // $c = mysql_fetch_array()
    for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {  // $d = mysql_fetch_array()
         echo $i;
    }
 }
```

By the time the inner loop has finished, $i is 10, which kills the inner loop, and then also kills the outer loop.